# Training in a background thread does not work well with Atari games

Tags: python, multithreading, tensorflow, reinforcement-learning

I've implemented several reinforcement learning algorithms using Tensorflow. For continuous methods(e.g. DDPG, TD3), I ran them on [BipedalWalker](https://gym.openai.com/envs/BipedalWalker-v2/); for discrete methods(e.g. DQN, Rainbow), I ran them on [Atari games](https://gym.openai.com/envs/#atari).

I intentionally split training and environment interaction by training the networks in a background thread(via the standard python module `threading.Thread`). I found this sped up those methods running on BipedalWalker, but it harmed those on Atari games. What makes these differences? Does it have something to do with python's [GIL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1294402/7850499)?

One reason I can conjecture is that background learning increases the learning frequency, which makes it more likely overfit and get stuck at a local optimum.